# PHP Replace Between Tags with Regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am having a heck of a time replacing the data between two tags.  I can't figure out the regex that will match this pattern.    `My tags are simply <!-- Model # Start --> and <!-- Model # End -->`

Code:

```
        $products[''.$row[0].''][2] = preg_replace("/(<!-- Model # Start -->).*(<!-- Model # End -->)/i", "$1$2", $products[''.$row[0].''][2]);
        echo $products[''.$row[0].''][2] . "\n";
```

Data: $products[''.$row[0].''][2]

```
Economical. 7 mils thick, tough & stretchy. Each roll cellophane wrapped. UL listed.

<!-- Model # Start -->
<p style='text-align: right;'>16736</p>
<!-- Model # End -->
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the concatenating of empty strings? `$products[''.$row[0].'']`. Trying to get something like `(string)` cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
/(.*<!-- Model # Start -->).*(<!-- Model # End -->.*)/im
```

Note the **m** flag for multiline matches.

In case you have multiple occurances of the tags, you could use a reluctant quantifier to get the first match, or use lookaround.

http://rubular.com/ helps for testing.

Comment: I think I jumped the gun to quick.  This code ... $products[''.$row[0].''][2] = preg_replace("/(.*<!-- Model # Start -->).*(<!-- Model # End -->.*)/im", "$1$2", $products[''.$row[0].''][2]);  ... matches in the Rubular but does not work.

Comment: actually I just needed a /ims , whatever the s does made it work multi-line.   Thanks, for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd match it like so...

```
$match = 'Model\s#\s';

preg_replace('/<!--\s?' . $match . 'Start\s?(.*?)\s?' . $match . 'End\s?-->/i', '<span>$1</span>', $row);
```